# Python file at GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have added a python file at google app engine. how to send a request to this file. Is this file needed to b executed explicitly?

Comment: what is this file doing . Not sure what you mean by added a file

Answer (score 2):

Your app.yaml file decides which python script to run, depending on the request URL.

See examples at the [Google Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html). You can even use regexp.

Comment: use app.yaml to manage url requests. The app.yaml file will execute whatever you'd like based on the url (usually a .py file), then that .py file can be used to once again filter down the request and execute a class that executes either a get or post request that can be used to render an html page or whatever.